# Calling node controller from node controller, how to send the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a **priceController** node which is a lot of code called by angular in many places.

Now I have another node called **frontpageController** which would like to call the **priceController** directly, instead having to go to angular to do it.

But I cannot figure out how to feed **priceController** with the data the correct way (from angular its easy cause its http post).

How do I call **priceController** from **frontpageController** and send the data which it needs (propertyID)?

This is **priceController**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
exports.getPrice = function(req, res) {
    console.log("priceController received: " + JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4));
    console.log("propertyID: " +req.body.propertyID);
    ...lots of code...
    res.json({error:false,priceFindResult})
    console.log("Sent data back to caller");
}
```

And this is **frontpageController**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
exports.getFrontpage = function(req, res) {

    // 
    // Call the priceController with the PropertyID
    // 
    var priceController = require('./priceController');
    var priceModel = require('../models/priceModel');
    var priceTable = mongoose.model('priceModel');
    var callPriceController = function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("=====START callPriceController=====")
        priceController.getPrice(
        [{ "propertyID": "WAT-606" }]
        ,function(err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("callPriceController Result: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
                console.log("=====RESOLVE callPriceController=====")
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('ERR callPriceController : ' + err));
            };
        });
    })};
```

The result in my node console is as follows

```
=====START callPriceController=====
priceController received: undefined
getFrontpage ERR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'propertyID' of undefined
```

So it looks like I actually call the **priceController** but does not manage to get the propertyID sent there.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you're going for here but the function `getPrice` takes the arguments req and res which are presumably supposed to be the request and response objects. When you call `getPrice` you're passing it an array and a function. Since the array doesn't have a property `body`, `req.body` is undefined so trying to access any property of `req.body` (in this case `propertyId`) is going to throw a TypeError. Even if you got past that point, though, it would error later when you tried to call `res.json` because you're passing it a function that doesn't have that method.

Maybe you could pass the req and res objects to `getPrice`?

Comment: Ahh yes - you are right, I have to parse the body.   How would you do that?

Comment: Got it to work by doing this:  `priceController.getPrice (
  { "body": { "propertyID": "WAT-606" } }` - but now the priceController complains that there is no "res" when it tries to return the data `res.json({error:false,priceFindResult})`